# Problem with connect Oracle DB sqlplus / as sysdba (unset TWO_TASK)

Tags: linux, oracle

I tried to connect `sqlplus / as sysdba` I get this error

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Dec 12 12:24:05 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name:
```

After unset TWO_TASK everything works well, why do I have to use unest TWO_TASK, and why is it used?

Thanks advance, Petar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing `sqlplus / as sysdba` or `connect / as sysdba` is called connecting using **operating system authentication**, and on Linux, [it's only supported for local connections](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/dba.htm#ADMIN11056) (ie, when you omit the remote server host string).

Using the `TWO_TASK` environment variable makes it impossible to use local OS authentication that way, since [it forces a default *remote* connection](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DFSIG/oracle-environment-variables.htm#DFSIG320) which is always used when the host string is omitted. Even if your TWO_TASK variable points to your local server, it's treated as a remote connection.